# Get uniq results from elastic search

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, kibana

Get single record in given date. If it have multiple records then return single uniq record in every request (If it have single record it can be return same retult).

```
      "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "site_name": "blog_new_post"
                    }
                },

                {
                    "match": {
                        "postdate_yyyymmdd": "20190715"
                    }
                }
            ]

        }

      },
      "size": 1
    }
```

I tried with size. So, size returning same record at some times.

```
{
    "took": 152,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1180,
        "successful": 1180,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 6624,
        "max_score": 3.6852486,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "some-*",
                "_type": "data-*",
                "_id": "8a9e351e92e6b9b26c8d8fb0173cadd9",
                "_score": 3.6852486,
                "_source": {
                    "uniq_id": "8a9e351e92e6b9b26c8d8fb0173cadd9",
                    "postdate_yyyymmdd": "20190715"

      }
    }]
   }
}
```

Uniq record based on uniq_id. Uniq id is different for every record.

Comment: on what criteria or field you want your records to be unique

Comment: @Hrithik Manchanda  i just updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to aggregate your results on the basis of aggregation.
As you said you want records based on uniq_id and I am assuming that you might have multiple records for this one id in your index and you want to return only one record for each uniq_id

You can refer to elastic search aggregations documentation. 
you can sort records by newest and fetch top_hits in your aggregation. specifying the size of top_hits as 1 would get you 1 record for your uniq_id

Refer to documentation for aggregation instructions

[Top_Hits Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

Comment: uniq_id different for every record. above get request passing through postdate (postdate will common for record not uniq_id).

Comment: if you have unique uniq_id then how can you get multiple records?

Comment: Because, postdate_yyyymmdd is common in records not uniq id. In get request searching through postdate_yyyymmdd (you can see it on question).

Comment: so you need records for a particular date as unique?

Comment: Yes, single uniq record in every get request. Note: I did this with back end. More happy if some suggestions to solve this. Thank you.